# Changing the color of the Sky (Sun Lamp)

Tags: light, world

With the Sun Lamp sky settings, is there any way to change the color of the sky (for example, a redder color for a sunset) or the color of the sun itself?

Comment: you want to change the color of the sun lamp, or change the color of an HDRI?

Comment: The sun lamp generates a sky background... I want to change that color. Changing the color of the light that comes.from the sun is easy enough but it does not change the corresponding atmosphere.

Comment: are you looking for the world color?

Comment: I think you mean changing the colour of the light, not the world background.

Comment: I'm referring to the effect controlled in the "Sky & Atmosphere" menu for the Sun Lamp object. Not the "Lamp" settings, nor the "World" settings. Is there a preferred place for hosting screenshots? It might be easier if I just circle the dialogue options I'm talking about and put that in the question.